# Buying on US OTC versus Canadian TSX

Tags: united-states, income-tax, adr

As a US citizen, is it better to buy an equity that is cross-listed both on the US OTC Exchange as an ADR, or to purchase it from an online broker that has access to the Toronto Exchange TSX or even TSXV? I'm not talking about penny stocks. However I know that there is a certain layer of safety if you purchase on a US Exchange since they are regulated by our SEC, and companies listed have to make filings and ostensibly comply with regulations.

However, previously when I invested in ADRs, the Canadian government had already withheld and taxed profits listed on my annual 1099 B from my US stockbroker. So when I was doing my tax return schedule D, it was a lot of rigmarole to get these monies refunded that I ended up just leaving about $200 and walking away. Also too much time and energy to write off as an investment loss. And considering overall picture of tax ramifications for my portfolio — both long and short-term capital gains etc. this was a deterrent to investing in precious metals and mineral companies that were/are incorporated in Canada as the majority of them are. This was about 10 years ago. Has anything changed?

Comment: "I know that there is a certain layer of safety if you purchase on a US Exchange since they are regulated by our SEC" — Are you sure about this? The US OTC stock market is very different from the market of exchange-listed stocks. It is not a "stock exchange", and the securities that trade on it are a lot less regulated than those that trade on US stock exchanges.

Comment: "... companies listed have to make filings and ostensibly comply with regulations" — Note that "level 1" ADRs have minimal regulatory requirements. Level 1 ADRs have no obligation to make annual filings! Please read: [Investor Bulletin: American Depositary Receipts](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/general-resources/news-alerts/alerts-bulletins/investor-bulletins-88).

Comment: "I know that there is a certain layer of safety if you purchase on a US Exchange since they are regulated by our SEC" — Aren't Canadian securities already regulated by Canadian securities regulators?